# How to incorporate NavigationExperimental.Navigator with react-native-circular-action menu?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, navigation, navigator

I know that I'm doing this all wrong.. but I am trying to build my first react native iOS app and so far the navigation part of this project is defeating me. :(

Can someone please guide me with the proper structure?
I want to be able to click on the buttons [(npm menu here)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-circular-action-menu) of the menu to direct to another page component. And my goal is to make this as modular as possible so I want to separate all the pages into its own separate components

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

here my code below:

import React from 'react'
import {
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Color
} from 'react-native'

import NavigationExperimental from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components'
import ActionButton from 'react-native-circular-action-menu'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import Home from './components/Home'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

```
        <View style ={styles.container}>
            <NavigationExperimental.Navigator
                // style={{ flex:1 }}
                initialRoute={{ name: 'Home' }}
                renderScene={ (route, navigator) => {
                    switch(route.name){
                        case(route.name == 'FAQ'):
                            return <FAQ navigator = {navigator}/>
                        case(route.name == 'Events'):
                            return <Events navigator = {navigator}/>
                        default:
                            return <Home navigator = {navigator}/>
                    }
                }}/>
             <Home/>
            {/*Rest of App come ABOVE the action button component!*/}
                <ActionButton buttonColor = "rgba(231,76,60,1)" style={styles.mainButton}>
                    <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#84ccc9' title="faq" onPress={() => {}}>
                        <Icon name="ios-help-circle" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
                    </ActionButton.Item>
                    <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#5b4d90' title="aboutUs" onPress={() => {}}>
                        <Icon name="ios-people" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
                    </ActionButton.Item>
                    <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#37a3da' title="events" onPress={() => {}}>
                        <Icon name="ios-calendar" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
                    </ActionButton.Item>
                    <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#91a1c9' title="homePage" onPress={() => {}}>
                        <Icon name="ios-home" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
                    </ActionButton.Item>
                    <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#e84d3d' title="cinthy" onPress={() => {}}>
                        <Icon name="ios-chatboxes" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
                    </ActionButton.Item>
                    <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#f6ba61' title="careerStats" onPress={() => {}}>
                        <Icon name="ios-pie" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
                    </ActionButton.Item>
                    <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#1abc9c' title="jobSearch" onPress={() => {}}>
                        <Icon name="ios-search" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
                    </ActionButton.Item>
                </ActionButton>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3'
    },
    actionButtonIcon: {
        fontSize: 20,
        height: 22,
        color: 'white',
    },
    mainButton:{

```
}
```

})

UPDATE**: By the way, I am using create-react-native-app not react-native init

so I don't have the AppRegistry.

I know that this navigation method will be deprecated. If you have another preference for navigation, I am open to checking out your preferred navigation and how that is structured.

Comment: You can use stack navigator. It is very easy to implement. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack

Comment: thank you! it took me some time to figure out how to implement that into the action button but its really really easy like you said! thanks a lot